# Flatten an array of integers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, unit-testing, recursion

The goal is to flatten an array of nested arrays of integers.
For example `[1, [2], [3, [4]]]` should return `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

I'm particularly looking for some feedback on the following:

- Is usage of `TypeError` exception justified?
- Did I miss some valid edge cases in my tests?

Here is my solution including unit tests:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest


def flatten_list(array):
    """ Returns a flattened array of integers from arbitrarily nested arrays of integers.

    >>> flatten_list([[1, 2, [3]], 4])
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
    """

    flat_array = []
    for element in array:
        if isinstance(element, int):
            flat_array.append(element)
        elif isinstance(element, list):
            flat_array += flatten_list(element)
        else:
            raise TypeError("Unsupported type ({})".format(
                type(element).__name__))
    return flat_array


class FlattenListTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Tests for flatten_list"""

    def test_empty_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(flatten_list([]), [])

    def test_single_integer(self):
        self.assertEqual(flatten_list([3]), [3])

    def test_already_flattened(self):
        self.assertEqual(flatten_list([1, 2, 3, 4]), [1, 2, 3, 4])

    def test_single_element_multiple_nested(self):
        self.assertEqual(flatten_list([[1]]), [1])

    def test_arbitary(self):
        self.assertEqual(flatten_list(
            [1, [2], [3, 4], [[5]], 6]), [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

    def test_empty_sublists(self):
        self.assertEqual(flatten_list([1, [[], 2]]), [1, 2])
        self.assertEqual(flatten_list([[]]), [])

    def test_invalid_input(self):
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            flatten_list(3)
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            flatten_list([3, "2"])
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            flatten_list(None)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Python normally promotes [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), yours is more statically typed.
- You may want to use `yield`, as your current code possibly uses more memory than needed.
- You can check if an item is iterable, and iterate it. Otherwise return the item.

  You can do this in two ways either via [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-lbyl) or [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-eafp).

Just using `yield` can get:

```
def flatten_list(array):
    for element in array:
        if isinstance(element, int):
            yield element
        elif isinstance(element, list):
            yield from flatten_list(element)
        else:
            raise TypeError("Unsupported type ({})".format(
                type(element).__name__))
```

Using LBYL and duck typing can then get:

```
import collections


def flatten_list(array):
    for element in array:
        if isinstance(element, collections.abc.Iterable):
            yield from flatten_list(element)
        else:
            yield element
```

Using EAFP and duck typing can instead get:

```
def flatten_list(array):
    for element in array:
        try:
            element = iter(element)
        except TypeError:
            yield element
        else:
            yield from flatten_list(element)
```

---

Finally as a side note, if you expect the initial array to have a depth exceeding one thousand, then you may want to instead perform the stack manipulation yourself. So you don't get a stack overflow error.
This can be done with something like:

```
def flatten(it):
    to_yield = [iter(it)]
    sentinel = object()
    while to_yield:
        item = next(to_yield[-1], sentinel)
        if item is sentinel:
            del to_yield[-1]
            continue
        try:
            item = iter(item)
        except TypeError:
            yield item
        else:
            to_yield.append(item)
```

Comment: Nice answer. One small nitpick: I would use a different name for `none` in the last Answer as this could be confused with `None`. How about `sentinel`?

Comment: @magu_ I agree, it confused another too. I've changed the `sentinel`.

Comment: Is it really duck typing you are using here? My understanding of duck typing was that it doesn't involve any explicit type checking (like `isinstance`) and the type of an object is determined at runtime. So in our example, we should be able to call `flatten_list` on both int and list objects. The problem is of course that Python doesn't support the extension of built-in datatypes.

Comment: @NikolayDerkach Yes the above _is_ duck typing, even the LBYL is, as that's checking if it quacks like a duck. And "The problem is of course that Python doesn't support the extension of built-in datatypes." is 100% wrong, `class MyList(list):pass` works fine. And you can add to it.

Comment: I meant extension as in "adding methods" to built-in classes (i.e. without inheritance), i.e. so that you can do something like `a = 5, b = [5]; a.flatten(); b.flatten()`